# PrimeFaces dialog validation errors

Tags: jsf, primefaces

What i want to do is like basic row selection example at Primefaces showcase(http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionByColumn.jsf) I want to update my datatable's row. The problem is when i click to update button at datatable, dialogbox appears with validation errors.

Second thing is what is the order of method execution times.(action-update-onclick-f:setPropertyActionListener)

```
<p:commandButton id="updateButtonId"
                                     action="#{myController.showCompanyEditPanel}"
                                     update=":tabView:companyForm:companyEditPanel"
                                     onclick="companyDialog.show()"                                         
                                     icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="update">  
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{company}" target="#{myController.selectedCompany}" />  
</p:commandButton>


<p:dialog id="editCompanyDialogId" header="CompanyEdit" widgetVar="companyDialog" resizable="false">
    <p:panel id="companyEditPanel" >
    //some stuff here
    </p:panel>
</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing a major point of using a `<p:commandButton>` here, as well as seem to be mixing client-side and server-side events.

First on `<p:commandButton>`. This component is designed to POST (partial) form data to the current URL, do business job in action(listener) method and return updated components / perform navigation. You can of course 'attach' JavaScript events to all those attributes.

Second, `onclick`, `oncomplete`, and other `on...` attribute are corresponding to some client-side events. In particular, `onclick` function is triggered when button was clicked, `oncomplete` function is called when DOM was updated after the AJAX call, i.e. the elements specified in `<p:ajax update="...">` or simply in `update="..."` attribute of `<p:commandButton>`.

Third, all action listeners (thus, `actionListener` attribute, `<f:actionListener>` tag, `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` tag) will be executed right in the order they are specified in your tag, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3909382/1820286) for more elaboration. The last one to be executed is `action` method, after which response is sent back.